# vbscript to read text files and extract data

Tags: vbscript

i am in need of script to extract number of **`note-ref_`** and **`#ref_`** presence in all **html** files

my folder structure will be

**D:\Count_Test**

wherein lot of folders and sub-folder will contain and in each sub-folder will have a ref.html, text.html file will contain **`note-ref_`** and **`#ref_`** text (apart these files, some other files such as xml, txt and imges and css sub-folder will contain)

I need to count for every single file how many times **`note-ref_`** and **`#ref_`** appeared and the results needs to capture in .csv file

can anybody help me by providing solution to extract text into csv file

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions:

Use the Scripting.FileSystemObject (FSO) to walk through files and sub folders to identify the scope of your actions.  Alternatively, you could capture the output of DIR /s /b D:\Count_Test*.html.

Once you know the list of files you'll need to open, you should read each of them using the OpenTextFile function of the FSO and loop through each row.  When you find what you're looking for, increase some sort of counter - perhaps in an array.

Finally once you've finished collecting the data, you can output your results by once again doing OpenTextFile, but this time opening your CSV file location and writing the data you've collected in the appropriate format.